# Adding wordpress Blog in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails application deployed on my home root directory of a domain and symlinked with my public_html/applicationname.com/. I wanted to install wordpress in applicationname.com/blog path. But rails ain`t allowing me to do so. I have tried a subdomain as well, but still, the routes are being handled by Rails.

What would be the best solution to deploy a blog along with Rails application ?

I can only think of .htaccess modification.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your blog into the rails' public directory.
That's the place for static files (and php ones are).

Comment: Tried that, application.com/blog/ is interpreted by Rails routing and doesn`t allow to view the blog.

Comment: I've just seen this : http://www.igvita.com/2007/07/04/integrating-wordpress-and-rails/
Look at the RewriteRules. It allows you to force some URL to use the static system files and not Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your rails app using Passenger then you can disable Passenger for a particular location. See section 5.8 of the [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html), which has an example for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful to anyone looking to solve this problem:
http://www.spotscore.com/blog/2009/11/22/how-to-host-wordpress-and-phusion-passenger-rails-app-on-the-same-domain/

Answer (score 0):

Check the post :

http://joomlist.com/2011/10/php-in-subdirectory-of-rubyonrails/.  it worked using passenger with apache.