# How to configure Wordpress and Rails app on a Mongrel + Apache server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, apache2, mongrel

I need to add a wordpress blog site to the same server (under the same domain name), but at "/blog" path. That is:

My rails app is at mysite.com, 
I want the blog site at mysite.com/blog.

I tried putting all wordpress files under my rails app /public/blog folder. But whenever I access mysite.com/blog, I got error saying "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

However, I can still access mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php, so it seems that it can run PHP scripts just fine.

My rails app is running on a mongrel+apache2 configuration.

Any idea how I can make the blog work with this rails app?

Thanks.

Comment: no *great* answers there, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554207/adding-wordpress-blog-in-a-rails-application

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself. if anyone having similar problems, please check the solution at http://harryche2008.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/how-setup-wordpress-blog-under-railss-public-directory/