# Correct approach to adding a wordpress site to an existing RoR site hosted on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, architecture

Hello I have an app developed for a client of mine. This app is hosted on heroku on domain http://www.mydomain.com. Client has limited technical knowledge and wants a system that will easily allow him to add/edit content on some sites. Example: customer wants to create a news page and edit it, or he wants to create a blog posts..... The customer does not want to edit the main pages that i have already created for the app. So i was thinking of adding a wordpress site under http://www.mydomain/com/extras and this will be a fully managed wordpress site that my client can edit himself. Is this the correct approach? i researched and apparently it is not easy to host worpress on heroku. your recommendation is highly appreciated

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding wordpress Blog in a Rails application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554207/adding-wordpress-blog-in-a-rails-application)

Comment: Does the wordpress site have to be hosted on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

[**Buildpacks**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)

If you want to install Wordpress on Heroku, you'll need to use a custom buildback (typically [this Wordpress buildpack](https://github.com/mchung/heroku-buildpack-wordpress))

As for running in a buried folder, I suppose it would work if you had the system set up correctly - you may need to create a custom buildpack to handle it all.

Some info for you:-

> When you git push heroku, Heroku’s slug compiler prepares your code
>   for execution by the Heroku dyno manager. At the heart of the slug
>   compiler is a collection of scripts called a buildpack.

What you'll be looking for is how to create a buildpack to help your application deploy correctly. If you put your Wordpress blog in the following Rails folder, it should be accessible at least (whether it will run is another matter, as the paths might be inconsistent):

```
/public/path/to/your/blog
```

This will give you the ability to access the blog from the following URL: `domain.com/path/to/your/blog`

--

**DNS**

Another way to achieve this would be to host your Rails app on `heroku`, whilst deploying the Wordpress site in some shared hosting.

You could then "route" a subdomain, or perhaps a deep folder, with your DNS setup on your host - allowing you to send the traffic to different hosts without the users noticing